# Starting Android service already running?

Tags: android, service, android-intent

Sure this is a trivial question. What happens if I start a `Service`, using the following code:

```
 startService(new Intent(this,myService.class));
```

and then I accidentally recall the above code, while the `Service` is yet running?

I'm afraid that the second call to `startservice` can create a new `Service` in order to have two different process executing at same time.

Comment: There can only be 1 instance of a service, so you don't have to worry about multiple calls.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

> I'm afraid that that the second call to startservice can create a new service in order to have two different process executing at same time.

No, on multiple counts:

- No, it will not create a new service. If the service is already running, it will be called with `onStartCommand()` again, to deliver the new `Intent`, but a second copy is not created.
- No, it will not "have two different process executing at same time", because a service runs in the same process as the rest of your app, by default.

Comment: I am using an intent service to download video from url. I am displaying the videos in a list by fetching from website. When a user clicks a list element, the downloading starts in the intent service. If the user click another element, the next downloading starts automatically after the first one is finished. This is really confusing me.

Comment: @AnkitGarg: That is precisely how an `IntentService` is supposed to behave.

Comment: So does that mean the onStartCommand holds(stacks) the new service call and executes it when first service is finished?

Comment: @AnkitGarg: `onStartCommand()` is called (relatively) immediately when you call `startService()`. In `IntentService`, it pops the command onto a work queue, to be processed by the background thread and `onHandleIntent()`. In the normal case, that queue is empty, because the service just started up. And, in the normal case, `onHandleIntent()` completes before a new command is sent, and so the service shuts down. In your case, you are sending a second command while the first is being processed, so the second command will be queued and processed immediately after the first one completes.

Comment: what happens in case of Service not intentService?

Comment: @Sudhasri: I am not certain what part of the above discussion concerns you. My answer holds for any type of `Service`. If you have further questions in this area, I suggest that you ask a fresh Stack Overflow question where you can explain what you want to know in greater detail.

Comment: @CommonsWare raised a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284436/what-actually-happens-when-startservice-is-called-multiple-times. Can you please help me with this?