# Android: Use AlarmManager to repeatedly call service that sometimes lasts longer than the repeat interval

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I want to start a service every 15 minutes. Most of the time it will quit in about 30 seconds, but there will be times the service lasts longer than 15 minutes. I don't think it would be good for the alarmmanager to start the service if the previous service call is still running.  I was considering setting up a flag in onStartCommand to have it simply return without doing anything if the service is running. But I'm not sure if this is the best way to handle it, as onStartCommand returns an int and I don't know what the system needs for this value. Is there a best way to do this?

Comment: But I heard from (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124115/what-happens-if-i-start-an-android-service-which-is-already-running) CommonsWare this: "No, it will not create a new service. If the service is already running, it will be called with onStartCommand() again, to deliver the new Intent, but a second copy is not created." What will the new intent do?

Comment: I see. But what if I don't want the service to start again until the next time its supposed to be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I heard from CommonsWare this: "No, it will not create a new service. If the service is already running, it will be called with onStartCommand() again, to deliver the new Intent, but a second copy is not created."

Yeah, that CommonsWare guy, he sure does write a lot... :-)

> I don't think it would be good for the alarmmanager to start the service if the previous service call is still running.

If you are using `IntentService`, this will not be an issue. The command from your second alarm will be enqueued, awaiting `onHandleIntent()` to wrap up from the first alarm.

If you are not using `IntentService`, you will need to have smarts in `onStartCommand()` to determine that your own thread is still chugging along, and therefore you want to skip the command.

> But I'm not sure if this is the best way to handle it, as onStartCommand returns an int and I don't know what the system needs for this value.

That doesn't really have anything to do with your problem. Just return `super.onStartCommand()`, or whatever your current `onStartCommand()` method is returning.

> But what if I don't want the service to start again until the next time its supposed to be called?

Well, you could replace the repeating alarm with one-shot alarms (use `set()`) and then set up the next alarm as part of wrapping up the work from the previous alarm.

Comment: Thanks. It's good to get it from the horse's mouth (I have two of your books)!