# What Actually happens when startService is called multiple times

Tags: android, service

I'm calling `startService()` multiple times with different intents for same service. It is clear that only one instance of service exists anytime and `startCommand()` is called for every `startService()`.

My questions are:

1. Is there any performance effects in calling `startService()` multiple times?
2. Will the intents be handled serially in the order of calling ?